# How to add TextView style that depends on the application theme android

Tags: android, textview, android-styles, android-dark-theme

In my fragment i have 2 TextView with black (Primary) and grey (Secondary) colors in light theme and also white (Primary) and grey (Secondary) colors in dark theme. I have added new styles for TextView in styles.xml and styles.xml (night). But if I change the theme in the application, the text remains the same as in the light theme. This is how it looks like:

**Light Theme:**

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.Light" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    //
    //
    //
</style>

<style name="Theme.Light.TextView" >
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.Light.TextView.Primary">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.Light.TextView.Secondary">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/grey</item>
</style>
```

**Dark Theme:**

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.Night" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    //
    //
    //
</style>

<style name="Theme.Night.TextView" >
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.Night.TextView.Primary">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.Night.TextView.Secondary">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/grey</item>
</style>
```

**And these TextView's in layout:**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mainText"
    style="@style/Theme.Light.TextView.Primary"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:text="First Text"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/secondText"
    style="@style/Theme.Light.TextView.Secondary"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Second Text"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mainText" />
```

[image: light_theme_example]

[image: dark_theme_example]